# about json file to var

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am working on D3.js graph

```
var links = [
    {source:"one",target:"two", type:"a", typeKBP:"a"},
    {source:"two",target:"three", type:"a", typeKBP:"a"},
    {source:"three",target:"four", type:"a", typeKBP:"a"},
    {source:"four",target:"five", type:"a", typeKBP:"b"},
    {source:"five",target:"six", type:"b", typeKBP:"b"},
    {source:"six",target:"seven", type:"b", typeKBP:"b"}
]
```

Instead of like this I want add that `[...]` this code into `sample.json` file.
After adding that how can I get data from JSON file as it is format.

Comment: d3.json("/assets/sample.json", function(json) {
    // code that uses the object 'json'
});

Answer (score 0):

This will do the xhr for you and parse it automatically

```
d3.json("/path/flare.json", function(json) {
    //rendering logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fist load the sample.json file using an XHR call. Once loaded you need to parse the JSON (which is simple a string) using

```
var links = JSON.parse(data).
```

Then you can simple use `links` as a JavaScript array,

Alternatively, you can search for a utility function that d3.js might have and does all that for you.

Check this link for all the possible ways to load external data using d3.js utility methods

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests